# python selenium - TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python, selenium

```
inboxlv1 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH('//*[@placeholder="Email address"]'))
inboxlv1.send_keys(parsed[0][0])
```

why is it not callable?

Comment: Show us the full traceback and enough code to reproduce the problem!

Comment: The problem is not "why 'str' is not callable?". The problem is "why are you calling it?". You should provide the traceback. And some more code. What is `By` and it's `By.XPATH`. If `XPATH` is a string, you can't call it.

Comment: Why do you think it should be callable?

Comment: I asked a new question with more information about my main problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'yourxpath')
```

You were using a Java style for Python instead do it like so. Calling xpath like a method.